# Applying borderSide color to TextField only when darkTheme is enabled

Tags: flutter, dart, border, textfield, darkmode

I was wondering if there was a way to apply a specific color to the `enabledBorder` of a `TextField()` when `darkTheme` is enabled. This is my `TextField()`:

```dart
TextField(
  obscureText: true,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    labelText: 'Password',
  ),
),
```

However, using the following code in my dark theme will apply a border coloring to every enabledBorder, which I want to avoid for obvious reasons:

```dart
inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[700]!)
  )
),
```

I also do **not** want to have the same color applied when using the regular theme, so I cannot apply it to just the `TextField()`. What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of Suvash inspired me to the following code:

```dart
TextField(
  obscureText: true,
  decoration: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor == bgColorDark
  ? InputDecoration(
    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[700]!)
    ),
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    labelText: 'Password',
  )
  : InputDecoration(
    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
    labelText: 'Password',
  ),
),
```

Note that `bgColorDark` is a dark background color used in my dark theme. I am aware that this creates some code repetition, but this is easier to read in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the theme is darkTheme or not in the TextField and give the border color accordingly.
First we get the current theme data. Place the below code inside build:

```
ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
```

Now we can check the value of Brightness to determine if dark theme is enabled. If dark theme is enabled, the value of brightness will be light. So your TextField would be:

```
TextField(
  obscureText: true,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    enabledBorder: Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.light ? OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[700]!)
    ) : InputBorder.none,
    labelText: 'Password',
  ),
),
```

Comment: themeData is undefined in this way, can I use something else? Also, wouldn't this make the border transparant in light mode?

Comment: How are you defining your theme then?

Comment: i have a theme.dart file with the following code:
`ThemeData themeDark(BuildContext context) {
  return ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
    primaryColor: blueColor, [...]
   ),
  );
}`

Comment: Okay, Inside BorderSide you can check the condition using this:
themeDark(context).brightness == Brightness.light ? Colors.grey[700]!:Colors.transparent
Just replace themeData with themeDark(context) and import your theme.dart file!

Comment: this works for the darkTheme, but if I switch my emulator to light mode again, the statement will also evaluate to `true`, and therefore applying the same color.

Comment: So you want to define border color based on the theme of Android/IOS system right?

Comment: Flutter actually does this for you by defining a theme for `theme:` and `darkTheme:` in the `return MaterialApp()` function. I think usage of `Theme.of(context).brightness` instead of `ThemeDark(context).brightness` is the thing to go with here, however, this still leads to an invisible border in the light theme.

Comment: I have updated my answer, now it would not show an invisible border on light theme!

Comment: I added an answer from myself inspired by yours by using in if/else statement. Thank you!

Comment: Sure, No problem!